# How to query a date in HQL (Hibernate) with Joda Time?

Tags: hibernate, orm, grails, hql, jodatime

I am sure that someone familiar with HQL (I am myself a newbie) can easily answer this question.

In my Grails application, I have the following domain class.

```
class Book {
  org.joda.time.DateTime releaseDate //I use the PersistentDateTime for persisting via Hibernate (that use a DATETIME type for MySQL DB)
}
```

In my HQL query, I want to retrieve books whose release date is included in range `date1`..`date2`

For instance I tried:

```
DateTime date1, date2
... 
def queryStr = "select * from Book as b where b.releaseDate > $date1 and b.releaseDate < $date2" 
def res = Book.executeQuery(queryStr)
```

But I got the exception `...caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token:`
The error token points to date format (for instance `2009-11-27T21:57:18.010+01:00` or `Fri Nov 27 22:01:20 CET 2009`)

I have also tried to convert date1 into a Date class without success

So what is the correct HQL code ? Should I convert to a specific format (which one?) using the patternForStyle method or is there another -cleaner- way to do it?

Thanks,

Fabien.

Comment: How does org.joda.time.DateTime map to your SQL? Is it directly to the field? java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar can map directly to a database field. For what it's worth, since DateTime is an aggregate object, the Grails plugin is probably using under the covers a custom mapping type (see sec 5.3 of Java Persistence with Hibernate).

Comment: As stated in the comment of the code, DateTime is using PersistentDateTime  custom mapping type from joda-time-hibernate library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm no Grails expert, but in java you'd normally make `date1` and `date2` query parameters and bind them as such:

```
String hql = "select * from Book as b where b.releaseDate > :date1 and b.releaseDate < :date2";
session.createQuery(hql).setDate("date1", date1).setDate("date2", date2).list();
```

I'm sure you can do something similar in Grails. If not, format your dates as `yyyyMMddhhmmss` (no spaces) and enclose them in single quotes - that way Hibernate would treat them as constants and MySQL will implicitly convert them to dates.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! 
After your response, I went into grails source code and found this for executing HQL queries:
Account.executeQuery( "select distinct a.number from Account a where a.branch = :branch", [branch:'London'] )
So I did the same for my scenario and it worked. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

I pointed out by ChssPly, you should declare `date1` and `date2` as query parameters (positional or named) and then bind them. Here, we'll use named parameters. The usual way to pass named query parameters with Grails is via a `Map`:

```
def queryStr = "from Book b where b.releaseDate > :date1 and b.releaseDate < :date2"
Book.executeQuery(queryStr, [date1: date1, date2: date2])
```

Check [`executeQuery()`](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) documentation for the syntax details of both options.

Comment: Hi Pascal
Thx for your help. I did exactly what you have written.

Answer (score 3):

You can also compare dates using the ISO8601 date format e.g:

```
select * from Book as b 
where b.releaseDate > '2009-11-27T21:57:18.010+01:00' 
and b.releaseDate < '2010-11-27T21:57:18.010+01:00'
```

I've tested this using MySql as the back end. Just remember to wrap the dates up as a string.